# Node.js memory leak when using .map to create an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

I'm making repeated requests to a website using node, and trying to debug a resulting memory leak. From using `node --inspect server.js` I have been able to guess that this is the code causing the problem (this is a section of a Promise, hence the "resolve()" at the end):

```
response.on('end', function () {
    //store response in variable
    bufferData = Buffer.concat(bufferData);
    try {
        var bufferDataDecoded  = thisProtocol.FeedMessage.decode(bufferData).entity;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Protocol Error:  "+e);
        resolve([0]);
    }
    var timeNow = new Date();
    var bufferDataMapped= bufferDataDecoded
    .map(obj=> {
        return obj.item_update
            .map(itemu=>{
            if ((itemu.quantityOld-itemu.quantityNew) > 0 ){
                return {
                "resultType": bufferType
                ,"itemID": itemu.itemID
                ,"quantityOld": itemu.quantityOld
                ,"quantityDiff": itemu.quantityNew - itemu.quantityOld
                };
            }
            else return false;
        })
    });
    var bufferDataMapped2= [].concat.apply([],bufferDataMapped);
    resolve(bufferDataMapped2);
});
```

From looking at the Comparison log coming out of --inspect and looked at with Chrome DevTools, it looks like node.js is saving these objects like:

```
 {
   "resultType": bufferType
   ,"itemID": itemu.itemID
   ,"quantityOld": itemu.quantityOld
   ,"quantityDiff": itemu.quantityNew - itemu.quantityNew
 };
```

...every time the program runs, and not deleting the old ones after it runs, which is quickly contributing to a memory overflow.  I created variables locally within the .map()  in an attempt to avoid this problem, and am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: `itemu.quantityNew - itemu.quantityNew`? Isn't that always `0`? Shouldn't it be `itemu.quantityNew - itemu.quantityOld`?

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the larger scope of how this is used. Something is saving references to the array when the promise is resolved.

Comment: There's also a bug in the catch, there's a `return` missing after `resolve([0])`.

Comment: To debug memory leaks, make a heap snapshot and inspect what is referencing the objects that should have gotten garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

I am missing some code, so, here is my conclusion. Take a look into this code:

```
bufferData = Buffer.concat(bufferData);
```

bufferData is a global variable, so in each execution is concatenating the previous executions data. Try assigning null in the end of each execution:

```
response.on('end', function () {
    ... rest of the code ...

    resolve(bufferDataMapped2);
    bufferData = null;
});
```

But, to have a better response I would like to see the rest of the code.